# usage of grep command using the file includes the numeric sequences

Tags: grep

I have a data file (seq_array) that includes the numeric sequences as follows:

```
seq 640094400 60 640180770
```

I have also another file (data_file) that includes the data need to be extracted with respect to the "seq_array". For example;

```
grep "640094400" data_file > first_grep
grep "640094460" data_file > second_grep
grep "640094520" data_file > third_grep
.
.
grep "640180770" data_file > last_grep
cat "all_greps" > final_grep
```

How can I perform the above greps using more compact codes?

Comment: You can `read` the values to be `grep`ped from a file in a _loop_ and run the `grep`s in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `-f file` to read patterns from a file:

  > `-f FILE`, `--file=FILE`
  > Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
- To not need an intermediate file for your `seq` output, use [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (`<(command)`)
- You may also add `-F` to let `grep` search fixed strings instead of patterns, which speeds it up.

---

The final command would be:

```bsh
grep -f <(seq 640094400 60 640180770) -F data_file > final_grep
```